# Can Anyone Explain how to make a Searchable DropDown to select countries using api/json? in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dropdown, flutter-dependencies

I want to make a dropdown list, in which one can select the country. The drop down list must be searchable, whenever we type a letter, the drop down list changes.
The drop down list is using a api/json data.
We are not making selection Manually.

Comment: What's the issue here? There are multiple packages like [searchable_dropdown](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown) that you can combine with a network call to achieve your goal. Please post your query if you have a problem regarding the implementation

Comment: can you explain how to use api data or json dat in a drop down?

Comment: plz it would be helpful if you explain how to combine the network call.

Comment: @Alita has already answered the query.  Regardless have a look here https://medium.com/flutterpub/making-a-network-call-in-flutter-f712f2137109,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [searchable_dropdown](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown) or [dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) packages

For **API/JSON** question :

check out the second package example in [Readme](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search#endpoint-implementation-using-dio-packagehttpspubdevpackagesdio)

example

```
DropdownSearch<UserModel>(
  label: "Name",
  onFind: (String filter) async {
    var response = await Dio().get(
        "http://5d85ccfb1e61af001471bf60.mockapi.io/user",
        queryParameters: {"filter": filter},
    );
    var models = UserModel.fromJsonList(response.data);
    return models;
  },
  onChanged: (UserModel data) {
    print(data);
  },
);
```

Comment: how to use Json data or api data in a dropdown?